# How to change with different textcolor for different list items of a listview in class extending Activity?

Tags: java, android, listview

i'm trying to set different textcolor for different list items of a listview. How to achieve it?
Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to define a custom adapter by extending **BaseAdapter**. Now define a class and extends BaseAdapter, inside it you can perform the change color kind of stuffs inside the **`getView()`** method.

For defining custom listview, [here](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/android-%E2%80%93-listview-%E2%80%93-5-%E2%80%93-optimized-custom-listview/) are examples for the same. Go through the examples and try to implement in your way.

Comment: @user370305 yes its obvious, because defining custom adapter is one time practice, if he/she tries to define it then he/she can easily use it for GridView/ListView

Comment: hi, i did as in the specified link. but only one list item is displaying. If i add another list item, the list showing empty.

Comment: my code goes here: ListViewCustomAdapter.java :http://pastebin.com/WC6WA9rS MainActivity.java :http://pastebin.com/rbb8T3nb Please refer my code and guide me.

Comment: you have to set the text color for particular position inside the getView() method, something like: if(position%2==0){ holder.textTitle.setTextColor(Color.Red)}

Comment: Check this exmaple, it is doing the same as i have mentioned above: http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/

Comment: colors getting fine. but i can get only one list item in my list. if more than one list item is present, the list is showing empty list view

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4654/discussion-between-paresh-mayani-and-pattabiraman)

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity related to the List.xml should extend from ListActivity class

inside onCreate method:

```
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(

         Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         data = new Vector<RowData>();//RowData should get you, your data     
         CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list,             R.id.title, data);     
         setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Add a new CustomAdapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

         public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {
                  super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);  
         }      
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){            
                  ViewHolder holder = null;         
                  if(position%2==0)
                     convertView.setBackgroundColor(color.darker_gray);
         } 
}
```